# java Supplier value cannot be modified?

Tags: java

I wrote a program as below:

```
public class Testing {

    Student student;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Supplier<Student> myStudent = Student::new;
        Student stu = new Testing().computeRequiredValue(myStudent).get();

        System.out.println(myStudent == stu);

        System.out.println(stu.getId());
    }

    public Supplier<Student> computeRequiredValue(Supplier<Student> valueToBePopulated) {
        Optional<Student> studentOptional = Optional.ofNullable(valueToBePopulated.get());

        if (studentOptional.isPresent()) {
            student = valueToBePopulated.get();
            student.setId("22");
            student.setName("Dbanga Srinu");
        }

        return valueToBePopulated;

    }

}
```

I see the outputs of System.out.println(myStudent == stu);

```
    System.out.println(stu.getId());
```

are false and null. I assumed as the myStudent and stu refer to the same object, on the heap, they should be modified and the condition myStudent == stu should return a true and stu.getId() should return a value.

Please help in understanding this.

Comment: `myStudent` and `stu` do **not** refer to the same object. `stu` refers to a student object and `myStudent` refers to a supplier function that invokes the constructor of `Student` when you call the `get()` method. And every time you call `get` it returns a new instance of `Student`.

Answer (score 3):

A `Supplier<Student>` is not a reference and any particular `Student`, but a function that supplied a `Student`.

This means that `myStudent == stu` are never going to be equal because they are not the same types.

As a `Supplier<Student>` is not a function, you are actually calling the `.get()` a total of 3 times, creating multiple different `Students`, one in your field, and one in the local variable.

Try changing your `computeRequiredValue` function to only call the supplier once, and return the `Optional` student instead.

```
public class Testing {

    static Student student; // changed this to be static so I can reference it in main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Supplier<Student> myStudent = Student::new;
        Student stu = new Testing().computeRequiredValue(myStudent).get();

        System.out.println(student == stu); // using the same types, this can now be true, assuming they are in fact the same instance

        System.out.println(stu.getId()); // prints 22
        System.out.println(student.getId()); // prints 22
    }

    public Optional<Student> computeRequiredValue(Supplier<Student> valueToBePopulated) {
        Optional<Student> studentOptional = Optional.ofNullable(valueToBePopulated.get());

        if (studentOptional.isPresent()) {
            student = studentOptional.get(); // get the optional, not calling the supplier again.
            student.setId("22");
            student.setName("Dbanga Srinu");
        }

        return studentOptional; // returns the optional
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
Supplier<Student> myStudent = Student::new;
Student stu = new Testing().computeRequiredValue(myStudent).get();
```

In other words:

```
myStudent = new X();
stu = myStudent().get();
```

Those are **not** the same objects; so == can never be true. 
Heck, those things are not even of the **same** class. You are trying to compare apples and an apple tree - how could that ever be the same?!

And beyond that: the **supplier** *supplies* `new` Student objects ... but I guess you got the point by now.

Comment: A supplier is probably more like an apple tree than an apple box.

Comment: Well, a magic apple box that is never empty. But I took your suggestion and changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `myStudent == stu` is `false`, is because you are comparing a `Supplier` and emits a `Student` and a `Student` object itself, they are different classes and certainly not the same instance of a class.

The reason that `stu.getId()` is null is because every time you call the `get()` method on the supplier it creates a new `Student`, the `Student` you set the id of, is never used again and will eventually be garbage collected.
The Student you print the id of has just been created.